# Google translate for unsupported languages

Tags: translation, machine-translation

I have a church with refugees that speak a language unsupported by google. I wanted to find a way to train google to use that language in the private translator API, but it doesn't let you do that for unsupported languages. I can provide language pairs for the language in question "kinyarwanda." but it won't let me set up the training. I have seen the translator toolkit as well but I don't know the language well enough to use it to full effectiveness. Does anyone know what I should be using?

Comment: This is an important question but its importance is mostly in areas other than programming. I vote to close this question here and add a link to the post on Google Translate Product Forum https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/translate/IeIOws-3ThA;context-place=forum/translate

Answer (score 0):

Google don't have any private translator API.

The best way to share your idea or request for improvement is by sending feedback directly to Google team.